# Keeping Variables in Scope when Running Commands as Another User

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command as a different user and save the return code for further processing.

Is this possible in bash?

```
ret=99
pid=1234
su - deploy -c "cd $PROJECT_ROOT; kill -9 `echo $pid`; ret=$?" >> mylog.log 2>&1
echo $ret  # <= $ret still equals 99 when I want it to equal 0 or 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like that.

```
ret=99
pid=1234
su - deploy -c "cd $PROJECT_ROOT; kill -9 `echo $pid`" >> mylog.log 2>&1
ret=$?
echo $ret
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work. $ret will equal the exit code of `su -c`

Comment: And the exit code of `su -c` is the exit code of the last command run. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: You're right, this part `>> mylog.log 2>&1` was throwing it off. I can only get it to work when running the command as root.